# Elements within a container are overlapping

Tags: html, css

On a page, I am trying to add sub-sections where you can add a title with a text box, and it must be centered.

This is how it looks:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="subsections">
   <div class="subsection">
      <div class="subsection-header"><input type="text" class="subsection-title"></div>
      <div class="subsection-right"><button class="iqsp-button-small red delete-section">X</button></div>
      <div class="subsection-content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.subsection {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #006eaf;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.subsection-header {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.subsection-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Now this is all great, it works as intended. However, my next step is to add a table below for creating the questions:

**HTML**

```css
.subsection {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #006eaf;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.subsection-header {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.subsection-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="subsections">
  <div class="subsection">
    <div class="subsection-header"><input type="text" class="subsection-title"></div>
    <div class="subsection-right"><button class="iqsp-button-small red delete-section">X</button></div>
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <table class="responstable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Mandatory</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is where it all gets messed up, and looks like this:
[image]

I can see what's happening, there's something to do with the positions being absolute, and then the table is starting at the same position, so it just overlaps.

Is there any css I can add to `.subsection-content` or anywhere, to make it start on the next line so to speak?

Comment: I made you a snippet - a [mcve] is always a good idea - the snippet does not look like your image

Comment: In your first screenshot; should the table appear below the blue button?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

> Here is your requirements

```css
.subsection {
  position: relative;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.subsection-header {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.subsection-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

.subsection-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
}

.responstable {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="subsections">
  <div class="subsection">
    <div class="subsection-header"><label for="header">Header : </label><input type="text" class="subsection-title" id="header"></div>
    <div class="subsection-right"><button class="iqsp-button-small red delete-section">X</button></div>
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <table class="responstable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Mandatory</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>10</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this works, but now everything below that is on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You are using for header an approach that will center it inside subsection both horizontally and vertically.

The later is not really convenient when the table is also inside subsection.

Lets fix it, centering only horizontally, and giving it some space on the top

```css
.subsection {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #006eaf;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.subsection-header {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: fit-content;
  top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.subsection-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="subsections">
  <div class="subsection">
    <div class="subsection-header"><input type="text" class="subsection-title"></div>
    <div class="subsection-right"><button class="iqsp-button-small red delete-section">X</button></div>
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <table class="responstable">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Mandatory</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```